# how to convert 8-bit unsigned int data to signed?

Tags: dart, integer, uint8list

I am getting List of `8-bit unsigned int` from a mic source for each sample rate which looks like this

```
[61, 251, 199, 251, 56, 252, 138, 252, 211, 252, 18, 253, 91, 253, 194, 253, 25, 254, 54, 254, 19, 254, 190, 253, 80, 253, 249, 252, 233, 252, 46, 253, 180, 253, 54, 254, 136, 254, 157, 254, 110, 254, 38, 254, 208, 253, 117, 253, 68, 253, 57, 253, 83, 253, 163, 253, 20, 254, 151, 254, 51, 255, 215, 255, 105, 0, 207, 0, 246, 0, 249, 0, 10, 1, 64, 1, 162, 1, 4, 2, 64, 2, 97, 2, 111, 2, 110, 2, 89, 2, 40, 2, 241, 1, 199, 1, 178, 1, 192, 1, 241, 1, 45, 2, 77, 2, 70, 2, 45, 2, 36, 2, 83, 2, 176, 2, 21, 3, 121, 3, 229, 3, 87, 4, 185, 4, 225, 4, 197, 4, 129, 4, 26, 4, 150, 3, 7, 3, 128, 2, 55, 2, 65, 2, 134, 2, 223, 2, 25, 3, 41, 3, 28, 3, 255, 2, 234, 2, 240, 2, 25, 3, 62, 3, 92, 3, 146, 3, 219, 3, 65, 4, 149, 4, 164, 4, 130, 4, 51, 4, 195, 3, 69, 3, 164, 2, 244, 1, 75, 1, 187, 0, 81, 0, 240, 255, 135, 255, 19, 255, 155, 254, 64, 254, 22, 254, 58, 254, 146, 254, 217, 254, 248, 254, 215, 254, 144, 254, 92, 254, 84, 254, 141, 254, 229, 254, 39, 255, 96, 255, 170, 255, 248, 255, 69, 0, 117, 0, 128, 0, 137, 0, 131, 0,
```

so how can I convert this into signed decimal value or someone can guide me to the right path

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what the bytes mean.

Looking at the bytes, every *other* byte is either very low or very high. That suggests to me that the bytes are really little-endian signed 16-bit values.

In that case, you just need to view them as such. If we assume that the platform is little-endian (most are), you can just do:

```dart
List<int> list = ...;
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list); //
Int16List words = Int16List.sublistView(bytes);
```

Then the `words` list contains signed 16-bit numbers.
(If the list is already a `Uint8List`, you can skip the first step.)

If that's not what the bytes mean, you'll have to figure out what they do mean.

Answer (score 0):

Dart int type provide a method to convert from signed to unsigned and from unsigned to signed.

For example:

```
int a = 16;
int b = 239;
print(a.toSigned(5).toString()); // Print -16
print(b.toSigned(5).toString()); // Print 15
```

the toSigned method parameter indicate the bit order of the sign bit.

You can get more information here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toSigned.html

A toUnsigned method exixts too: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/toUnsigned.html